# Is it possible to mix constructor and field injection in Dagger?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger

I'm trying to use Dagger for my android project but I encounter a Problem: Is it possible to mix constructor and field injection? 
I have a module and two classes:

```
@Module(injects = fooActivity.class)
public class Module {
    private fooActivity activity;

    public Module(fooActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Provides
    public bar provideBar() {
        return new bar(activity);
    } 
}

public class fooActivity extends Activity {

    @Inject Baz baz;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        ObjectGraph graph = ObjectGraph.create(new BasicModule()).plus(new Module(this));
        graph.inject(this);
    }
}

public class bar {

    @Inject Baz baz;
    @Inject FooActivity activity;
    public bar(FooActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }
}
```

The problem is that 'baz' in the class 'Bar' is always null after the injection. It works though, if I don't use a provide method but only use field injection and handle all dependencies in 'Module'. 
So from my point of view there are three possibilities: 
1) Do field injection only and handle all dependencies in module classes.
2) Do constructor injection only and have all dependencies as constructor parameters. 
3) Mix both but call .inject(this) on a ObjectGraph-object in the constructor to satisfy fields with @Inject annotation.

Is this correct?

EDIT:
I cannot use complete constructor injection because 'baz' is declared in another module. Editing the example.

```
@Module(includes = Module.class)
public class BasicModule {
    @Provides 
    public baz provideBaz() {
        return new baz();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is possible. I think you want to add your activity graph to your main application graph in dagger.

Check out https://github.com/square/dagger/tree/master/examples/android-activity-graphs.

Also your class bar, you should probably do complete constructor injection. But if you MUST do it the way you are doing, you need to call inject and register bar in a module.  Here is the way I would create Bar.

```
public class Bar {
    private final Activity activity;
    private final Baz baz;

    @Inject public bar(FooActivity activity, Baz baz) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.baz = baz;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have two different modules so that I cannot use complete constructor injection. So in my case I would have to define Bar as an injects-point in Module, create a new ObjectGraph like in onCreate() of Foo and call graph.inject(this) ?

Comment: I have many modules in my application and I use constructor injection. You should only really use field injection on Activities, Fragments, and Views since you are stuck using there default constructors.  Could you explain more on why you don't think you can use constructor or show me the error you are getting? Like I said before I think you need to add your activity module to your application module.

Comment: With adding the activity module to the application module you mean 'ObjectGraph.create(new BasicModule()).plus(new Module(this));'

Comment: Yup, except you want to get your application graph rather than creating it in your activity. Please see that github link I posted in the answer.

Comment: My example is shortened. BasicModule actually is the application graph which gets created in a class which extends Application.

Comment: Np, hopefully this helps. Without seeing all the code it's hard for me to point out the exact issue. I'm assuming you are trying to get access to Bar in your activity. If not there might be some other issues.

Comment: Yeah, you helped. It works now. The problem was that I had misconceptions about what Dagger can and cannot do. I am used to more or less only use field injection from some work with Spring beans. Thanks again.